# How Can I Use a Custom AccessFileName?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have a need to have a custom `AccessFileName` setting in my virtual hosts, however it appears that `save_mod_rewrite_rules` function assumes that `.htaccess` is the name for everyone.

How can I override that function safely?

Comment: I don't see how you can unfortunately. WP core only writes to that file when your permalink structure changes, so if that's all you're using it for you can just manually rename the file.

Comment: I think I may be able to have a shared .htaccess if the rules per permalink structure aren't changed that much I can likely just remove the `# WordPress Changes Here` section once a site's permalink rules are setup and add a Rewrite Cond statement with domain specific language is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

The filename is hard-coded into the core WordPress function with no way to override it by way of filters or other hooks.